# C - Single Linked List: problems with scanf and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, scanf

*Ok this is going to be a really bad question, I can't figure out how to assign a float number with scanf:*

```
float get_value(float * ptr){

printf("Immettere valore: ");
scanf("%f", &(*ptr)); //THE ERROR IS HERE 

return *ptr; }
```

*Don't really know what to do here. (THE ERROR IS HERE in the code)
Here is the other interested part:*

```
...        switch (ch) {
        case 1: *value = get_value(value);
            break;
        case 2: pre_insert(&listA, value);
            break;
        case 3: pre_insert(&listB, value);
            break;
        case 4: end_insert(&listA, value);
            break;
        case 5: end_insert(&listB, value);
            break;

        default: printf("\nComando non valido.\n");
            break;
    }

}...
```

*function prototipe:* `float get_value(float*);`

Comment: When you say "THE ERROR IS HERE", ***what is*** the "ERROR"? And what is `value`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And of course [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `*value = get_value(value);` is strange. Why not simply `get_value(value);`. Please show the declaration of `value`. BTW the question title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, you're just trying too hard

```
float get_value(float * ptr){

    printf("Immettere valore: ");
    scanf("%f", ptr); //THE ERROR IS HERE 

    return *ptr;
}
```

`scanf()` requires a pointer for reading a float, and `ptr` is already that.

And also, you should really pick one method for returning the value, either within the `pass-by-reference` parameter, or via `return`, you generally don't need both.  So do

```
float get_value() {
    float num;
    printf("Immettere valore: ");
    scanf("%f", &num); //THE ERROR IS HERE 

    return num;
}

float value = get_value();
```

or

```
void get_value2(float *ptr) {
    printf("Immettere valore: ");
    scanf("%f", ptr); //THE ERROR IS HERE 
}

float value;
get_value2(&value);
```

`Some Programmer Dude` makes a good point, I wonder if there is an error where you are trying to use the return value?

```
case 1: *value = get_value(value);
```

Looks somewhat suspect to me, unless `value` really is `float *value`

Comment: While this is good advice, it's not an "ERROR", or even an error. In `&(*ptr)` the address-of `&` and dereference `*` operators simply cancel each other out. The expressions `&(*ptr)` and `ptr` are the same.